# Postgresql windows server ssl compression not working

Tags: postgresql, ssl, compression, npgsql

Using Postgresql 9.5 x64 on Windows, I enabled SSL (with default allowed ciphers "HARD:MEDIUM:!aNULL") and SSL Compression checked.

I am not interested in encryption, I want to test if my application performs better with compression over the wire.

PGAdmin connects fine.
My Npgsql client also connects fine.

But analysing network traffic, it shows there is no compression over the wire (no difference in total data compared to without ssl).

My suspicion is the OpenSSL that postgresql is using, is not using ZLIB to compress, or my client isn't.

Using "openssl s_client connect" to the server it says: COMPRESSION: NONE in it's response.

How can I get SSL Compression working on my Postgresql 9.5 x64 windows server?

Update: I compiled an OpenSSL.dll with ZLIB enabled (https://github.com/openssl/openssl/tree/OpenSSL_1_0_2-stable). Placed the resulting libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll in PostgreSQL/9.5/bin folder.
Now when I connect using PgAdminIII and enable SSL Compression, I do get compression over the wire.

Using Npgsql (ado.net provider) however, no compression. Can I conclude npgsql does not support SSL Compression? Or can I do something to make a npgsql client use compression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building my own openssl including ZLIB, enabled compression on the postgresql server backend. And with a C++ client using libpq and connecting using sslcompression=1 in connectionstring it uses compression.

A select query taking 10MB of data transmission, was reduced to about 1MB with ssl compression.

Npgsql does not seem to support ssl compression at this moment (v3.0.5).

Answer (score 0):

By default, Npgsql 3.0.x uses an internal implementation of TLS/SSL which (probably) doesn't support compression. You can pass the setting `Use SSL Stream=true` in the connection string to make Npgsql use the .NET SSLStream implementation instead, which would probably support compression.

In 3.1 we may remove the internal implementation to default back to SSLStream.